# Shorten path of REST service in JBoss Seam application still wrong

Tags: java, rest, jboss, seam, url-pattern

I got a similar question as:
[Shorten path of REST service in JBoss Seam application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248814/shorten-path-of-rest-service-in-jboss-seam-application/3248902#3248902)
But couldn't comment on the shipmaster answer because of my initial rep. His comment Jul 19 at 18:10 misunderstood the situation:

Faces servlet is mapped by url-pattern `*.xhtml` and Seam Resource Servlet is mapped to `/*`. The `/*` now gets all the url patterns, even those of `*.html`, because it has more priority on url-pattern matching.

What can I change on components.xml in the code (default behavior):
`<resteasy:application resource-path-prefix="/rest"/>` 
and on web.xml in the code below:

```
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In a way that my RestEasy resource could be accessed by a path like `/rest/<resource>` instead of `/seam/resource/rest/<resource>` without invalidating my `*.xhtml` faces servlets (using his hint of change Seam Resource Servlet url-pattern to `/*` )?

(It is basically the unsolved question of kongo09 better detailed).

Comment: I've tried variations like: 
a) <url-pattern> /rest/* </url-pattern> and <resteasy:application resource-path-prefix="/"/> or

b) <url-pattern> / </url-pattern> and <resteasy:application resource-path-prefix="/rest"/>

But unsucessfully...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a url-rewriting solution. Seam/RestEasy still gets the full URL, but the client will get a pretty short URL.

If you're using AJP and Apache as a front-end, you could go with httpd's standard mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html.

If you can afford JSF2, a simpler solution is PrettyFaces http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/